# How to add multiple records into a SQL Server table from a gridview?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I got a csv file and I'm inserting it to a gridview, then displaying it. After that, I need to store it into the database, all the records from the gridview.

So on button click I'm using the following code :

```
using (SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local); Database='WaselProject'; Integrated Security = yes;"))
{
    scn.Open();
    string query = "INSERT INTO Wasel_Card (RECORD, CARD_ID, FULL_NAME, SERVICE_ID, PROC_COUNT, READ_COUNT) VALUES (@record, @cardid, @fullname, @serviceid, @proccount, @readcount)";

    using (SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand(query, scn))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@record", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Record"].Value.ToString());
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cardid", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CARD_ID"].Value.ToString());
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullname", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["FULL_NAME"].Value.ToString());
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@serviceid", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["SERVICE_ID"].Value.ToString());
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@proccount", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["PROC_COUNT"].Value.ToString());
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@readcount", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["READ_COUNT"].Value.ToString());

            scm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

but I get an error:

> Additional information: The variable name '@record' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should the using statement be inside your for loop? It doesn't begin a new one and you're trying to assign the same parameter multiple times?

Comment: If the DGV has a datasource based on that table, you dont need any of that code. Just update using the DataAdapter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you keep defining the parameters inside the loop and obviously the same parameter cannot be defined many times for the same command. Two ways to fix your issue.

**Method 1**

Call `Clear()` on your parameters within the loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@record", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Record"].Value.ToString());
    scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cardid", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CARD_ID"].Value.ToString());
    scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullname", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["FULL_NAME"].Value.ToString());
    scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@serviceid", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["SERVICE_ID"].Value.ToString());
    scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@proccount", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["PROC_COUNT"].Value.ToString());
    scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@readcount", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["READ_COUNT"].Value.ToString());
    scm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    scm.Parameters.Clear();
}
```

**Method 2**

Only add the values within the loop but declare your parameters once outside the loop.

```
// Define here just once
var paramRecord = scm.Parameters.Add("@record", System.Data.SqlDbType.Variant ); // There are 6 Add methods in total. 5 of them return SqlParameter so you can use any of those 5
// the other parameters
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    paramRecord.Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Record"].Value.ToString());
    // other parameter values here
    scm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: the second method: paramRecord.Value the .Value is underlined by red (error) ??@CodingYoshi

Comment: See my edit please. In the future you can just press F12 when your cursor  in on the method of interest, in this case Add, and it will go to the method you are using. The method I was using was returning int (the index) of the parameter in the collection so to use that you would write `scm.Parameters[int which was returned].Value. Now I am using another method which returns a SqlParameter object and that has Value property.

Comment: i used this but an error occurred:   Additional information: Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to nvarchar is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: I do not know what types your columns are. If your column is Integer then select SqlDbType.Int and if it is NVarchar select that when you are defining your parameters. If you put a dot after SqlDbType it will show you all the types so select the one you need for your parameter.

Comment: yeah i'm using nvarchar then also another error occurred badly:                Additional information: Invalid index 1 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=1. @CodingYoshi

Comment: Sorry but if you do not add all your parameters then it will not work. I added one for you, you need to add all the other ones. I even left you comments in the code.

Comment: i know but i'm testing it on only one record and the other records can be null in database.. @CodingYoshi

Comment: I am surprised you are still stuck on this problem. If the first approach works then why don't you just use that and go on with your project? If you need help then message me this evening and I will help you with this over chat.